# How to care for a weathered fiberglas camper roof?

Tags: repair, paint

I recently bought an 18-year-old pop-up camper with a fiberglas roof. There are no holes and it's still waterproof, but the paint (if it was ever painted) or resin has weathered and become powdery and the glass fibers are becoming exposed.

What should I recoat it with, and how should I prepare the surface?

Comment: This isn't mechanical maintenance and bodywork repairs are a bit off-topic too, but you could research into properly preparing and applying a **gelcoat** over the entire surface. Manufacturers or suppliers will have advice as to how to prepare the surface, and apply the gelcoat.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was going to ask in DIY but anything vehicle-related is off-topic there.

Comment: I hope the refurb goes well.

Comment: @WeatherVane - While I agree with you about it not necessarily being "mechanical maintenance", I think an answer here will benefit someone working on a vehicle with fiberglass. Yah, a borderline question, but I personally think we can roll with it.